# toggle between full and no visibility

Tags: javascript

I'm quite new to JS, and for the past few weeks I have been trying to make a google extension where you press a button to toggle the visibility of the page.

The following chunk of my code is where I call for a function to run on a page when '`var sol`', the variable used to check if the button has been pressed an odd or even number of times, equals an even number:

```
if (sol % 2 == 0) {
  sec = 20;     
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: 'functionNoVisibility.js'});
}
```

and this would be the function called:

```
function inContent() { 
  const el = document.getElementsByTagName("html"); 
  for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) { 
    el[i].style.display = "none"; 
  } 
}
```

and this is the `permissions` part in my manifest:

```
"permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "*://*"
]
```

the problem is that the html does not change. How can I fix this?
If the code provided isn't enough just tell me, I'm new to StackOverFlow...
Thanks in advance

Comment: I dont know about your whole approach but think you can not set display to none on `HTML` tag itself. Target `body`. Also there is one tag `html`, no need to loop it with `getElementsByTagName`, also there is one `body` as well. It can not have more of those. So you should do : `document.querySelector("body").style.display = "none"` no loops needed

Comment: @ikiK thanks for the help! I did not know about this particular feature of the `html` tag and about the loop thing.

Comment: @ikiK you mean like: https://jsfiddle.net/RokoCB/4vtebsx8/ 

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan ffs, well I did say "but I think "

Answer (score 0):

To summarize ikiK's answer posted in the comments:

- The content of the page is listed in body not in html
- You don't need a loop because there can only be on body element.
- document.querySelector("body).style.display = "none"; should do the trick

End of ikiK's anwer

Personally I would suggest to use the opacity property, if you want to be able to toggle the displayed page on and off. If I were to re-enable the page you'd probably set the display of body to "block", but this could mess with the overall design of the webpage. So I think it would be wiser to use opacity for your case.

Hope I could help :)